# Default access modifier for a method in interface in java?

Tags: java, methods, interface, access-modifiers

What is the default access modifier for a method in interface in java ? And what should be the access modifier of the implementation for its package private method ?

```
public interface FooBar{
    public void Foo();
    void Bar();
}
```

Comment: The access modifier for methods defined in an interface is always `public`.

Comment: @Laf So, by default its not package private ? Is it public ?

Comment: More info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html